# How to create REST requests with Magento 2 API in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, magento2

I made a small project to test communication between C# and Magento 2 API. I followed some tutorials but did not find a functional example.

1.
When I connect with admin user "/rest/V1/integration/admin/token", the request return the token, but when I try to add a category with "/rest/V1/categories" this is the response of the request:
{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Catalog::categories"}}

2. When I try to connect with a customer user (apiuser) "/rest/V1/integration/customer/token", the response of the request is "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."

apiuser have the role "Web Service Role" and "Web Service Role" have Roles Resources: "All"

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MagentoRestApi
{
public class Magento
{
    private RestClient Client { get; set; }
    private string Token { get; set; }

    public Magento(string magentoUrl, string userName, string passWord)
    {
        Client = new RestClient(magentoUrl);
        Token = GetAdminToken(userName, passWord);
    }

    public string GetAdminToken(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        var request = CreateRequest("/rest/V1/integration/admin/token", Method.POST);
        //var request = CreateRequest("/rest/V1/integration/customer/token", Method.POST);
        var user = new Credentials();
        user.username = userName;
        user.password = passWord;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, Formatting.Indented);

        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = Client.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return response.Content;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private RestRequest CreateRequest(string endPoint, Method method)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, method);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        return request;
    }

    public string CreateCategory(string categoryName)
    {
        var request = CreateRequest("/rest/V1/categories", Method.POST, Token);
        var cat = new ProductCategory();
        var category = new Category();
        category.Name = categoryName;
        cat.Category = category;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cat, Formatting.Indented);

        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = Client.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return response.Content;
        }
        else
        {
            return ":( "+ response.Content;
        }
    }
    public string CreateCategory(int id, int ParentId, string categoryName, bool IsActive, bool IncludeInMenu)
    {
        var request = CreateRequest("/rest/V1/categories", Method.POST, Token);
        var cat = new ProductCategory();
        var category = new Category();
        category.Id = id;
        category.ParentId = ParentId;
        category.Name = categoryName;
        category.IsActive = IsActive;
        category.IncludeInMenu = IncludeInMenu;
        cat.Category = category;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cat, Formatting.Indented);

        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = Client.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return response.Content;
        }
        else
        {
            return ":(" + response.Content;
        }
    }

    private RestRequest CreateRequest(string endPoint, Method method, string token)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, method);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        return request;
    }
}

public class ProductCategory
{

    [JsonProperty("category")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parent_id")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("position")]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("level")]
    public int Level { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("children")]
    public string Children { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("path")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("available_sort_by")]
    public IList<string> AvailableSortBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("include_in_menu")]
    public bool IncludeInMenu { get; set; }

}

public class StockItem
{

    [JsonProperty("item_id")]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_id")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stock_id")]
    public int StockId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("qty")]
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_in_stock")]
    public bool IsInStock { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_qty_decimal")]
    public bool IsQtyDecimal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("show_default_notification_message")]
    public bool ShowDefaultNotificationMessage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_min_qty")]
    public bool UseConfigMinQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("min_qty")]
    public int MinQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_min_sale_qty")]
    public int UseConfigMinSaleQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("min_sale_qty")]
    public int MinSaleQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_max_sale_qty")]
    public bool UseConfigMaxSaleQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("max_sale_qty")]
    public int MaxSaleQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_backorders")]
    public bool UseConfigBackorders { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("backorders")]
    public int Backorders { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_notify_stock_qty")]
    public bool UseConfigNotifyStockQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("notify_stock_qty")]
    public int NotifyStockQty { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_qty_increments")]
    public bool UseConfigQtyIncrements { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("qty_increments")]
    public int QtyIncrements { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_enable_qty_inc")]
    public bool UseConfigEnableQtyInc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("enable_qty_increments")]
    public bool EnableQtyIncrements { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("use_config_manage_stock")]
    public bool UseConfigManageStock { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("manage_stock")]
    public bool ManageStock { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("low_stock_date")]
    public object LowStockDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_decimal_divided")]
    public bool IsDecimalDivided { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("stock_status_changed_auto")]
    public int StockStatusChangedAuto { get; set; }
}

public class ExtensionAttributes
{

    [JsonProperty("stock_item")]
    public StockItem StockItem { get; set; }
}

public class CustomAttribute
{

    [JsonProperty("attribute_code")]
    public string AttributeCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class M2Product
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sku")]
    public string Sku { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attribute_set_id")]
    public int AttributeSetId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("visibility")]
    public int Visibility { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type_id")]
    public string TypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extension_attributes")]
    public ExtensionAttributes ExtensionAttributes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product_links")]
    public IList<object> ProductLinks { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("options")]
    public IList<object> Options { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("media_gallery_entries")]
    public IList<object> MediaGalleryEntries { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tier_prices")]
    public IList<object> TierPrices { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom_attributes")]
    public IList<CustomAttribute> CustomAttributes { get; set; }
}

}
```

And the form code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MagentoRestApi
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //static private string userName = "apiuser";
    //static private string passWord = "blablabla";

    static private string userName = "admin";
    static private string passWord = "albalbalb"; 
    static private string siteAddress = "http://magento.nxm.ro/";
    Magento objMagneto;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        objMagneto = new Magento(siteAddress, userName, passWord);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void adgClasa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // id, ParentId, name, IsActive, IncludeInMenu
        MessageBox.Show(objMagneto.CreateCategory(10, 0, "PC Components", true, true));
        //MessageBox.Show(objMagneto.CreateCategory("PC Components"));
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

watch your token, it comes with extra characters
use something like this:

token = token.Replace("\"", "");

Do you have any code to create a new product?